# App buttons gradient critique

Tags: gradient, critique

I am currently working on this part of my app where the user has to select what do they want to advertise. The color palette I use in my app is mostly grey, a little bit of black and then a gradient of these two colors, so I thought this would look neat.

Once I sketched it in Photoshop I found it personally pretty cool, but a little bit odd looking, so I want to hear your critiques!

**Does the gradient make sense or does it only make the design more obnoxious?**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look so bad in my opinion , I think it's pretty neat, there are just some tweaks which I would do.

I would start with suggesting you drop the white half moon backdrops, it's very distracting (will replace with a drop shadow later - much cleaner):

[image]

Then, I think, you should consider making it all one continuous gradient, instead of 4 separate ones:

[image]

I feel like it creates a nice flow to it, which makes it look really nice.

---

#### After adding in a 30% darkness drop shadow:

[image]

---

**How it could look with eight icons, plus other color variations which also looked pretty neat:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Only one thing though, I really liked your idea of a continuous gradient instead of 4 separate ones. Thing is, in reality there is more than 4 of those buttons, but you have got to scroll to see them, is the continuous gradient still good in 8 buttons or because there are so many the continuous gradient would look worse than having a gradient on each button?

Comment: @Levon I just tested it out, and it still looks pretty cool to me (obviously not **as** cool, but it doesn't look bad IMO)

Comment: @Levon I made a really quick mockup on [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/qQkuW6Y.gifv) so you can see.

Answer (score 2):

When there are doubts about the colors in UI design, especially with gradients, it's very useful to preview how people with problems in color distinction, the 8% of users will see it:

[image]

Sometime this type of exercise leads to the conclusion that color is not as important as the form. In the example of the question, the four icons seem extracted from four different cliparts styles, where the only common element, beside the color, is the nearly invisible white semicircle of the background.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you advise for removing the white semicircles? What would you change about it in order to make it look better, without taking into account the color?

Comment: The white semicircle will not fix anything, be there or not. My answer is that instead of worrying about colors you should do it for the icons and create a better, more systematic and customized design for your application.

Comment: Okay I see your point but how would I go about it? I consider myself pretty bad at designing (coming up with design mostly). I am just asking for some tips on how to have a more (as you said) systematic and customized design. Thanks

Comment: I put the comment in the answer to show that if there is a problem in your app it's not the color, but the design. Answering what these problems can become is another answer, impossible to describe in a comment. As a simple thing I can tell you an example: there are two flat icons and two isometric.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of advice I am asking for! Thanks for taking your time!