# Good way to highlight important values in limited space

Tags: interface-design, mobile, android

In my app I have a card that looks like so:

[image]

In which I want to highlight to the user certain values when, for example, there is less than a day left, the card is less than a kilometer away or when it is free.

I don't find a way of highlighting a value while keeping a cohesive design.

Things I came up with (Given that gradients are a common theme in my app):

[image]
[image]

Comment: I suppose you could consider highlighting the entire card too in some way. Like for example a colored border or something.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose to be clear and prominent in highlighting.

[image]

[image]

Sample color is irrelevant. Alter to fit the app theme.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way that I pointed out in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/114069/120647), the color codes are very striking but equally complicated, there are people who don't distinguish them, especially in text. I think that if it's an important information it should be accompanied by a formal highlight in addition to the color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Background the entire text area using the gradient for those 'close by/expiring soon/free' offer cards. Or white background, but with a thick gradient border around the entire card including photo. Basicly the 'highlight' offers card.
- Background white for over 1 km or longer expiration date or paid offers. The 'normal' offers card.
- Introduce 3 icons for distance, time, price.
- Use a different font combination, look at the typography in some popular apps.